# Create PowerShell aliases for Python 3.10 and Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, powershell-5.0

is it possible to set a permanent alias in PowerShell so that I can distinguish between the python versions? I would imagine it to work something like this: `python310 --version` would yield `3.10.0` and `python39 --version` would give me `Python 3.9.8`. Also, I would like to be able to use these aliases for any other python related terminal uses such as installing packages e.g. `python310 -m pip install matplotlib`.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could rename python.exe in your instalation folders to python39.exe/python310.exe and add them to your path.

Better option is to use python version manager.